# How to use `IsEqual` to create a utility that asserts the equality of type types

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I write in TypeScript and also use the [`type-fest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-fest) npm package.

In my code, for documentation purposes, I sometimes like to add assertions that two types are indeed equal or unequal. E.g. like the following:

```
const b: IsEqual<{a: 1}, {a: 1}> = true;
console.log(b);
```

If the types passed to `IsEqual` weren't equal the first line in the above code would fail during type-checking by the TS compiler. The second line is just to get rid of the TS error `variable b is defined but not used`.

So far so good.

Now I want to create a small utility that would allow me to assert the equality of two types even more succinctly, like so:

```
function type_fest_is_equal_assertion<T, S>(): void {
      let R: IsEqual<T, S> = true; // * 
      console.log(R);
}


 // with the idea that I can then simply write:
type_fest_is_equal_assertion<{a: number}, {a: number}>()
```

Unfortunately, the above code fails during compilation at the line marked with the asterisk (`*`) with:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'IsEqual<T, S>'.

Playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAkgZwKICOArgIYA2cAvnAGZQQhwDkSqAtDSjjEwFD8BjCADtucAEYAubPmLkAPOhLSAjJQA0GZXDUA%20OAF4EUIigDcvIaIhkUAOjIQA5gApxASgu8aRYQJjAIgjIKAD6nNyhwDihKHJkoSQ4OCiwgcLyACqaAMq6Lu7SAG4QwAAmGLxwcFVwtvAAStK4hKRkWbn6RjAm5rVWODb2jq4NnryU-LysYREwUTFxbYnJqQEiitpqmuhSOpT57kA).

Is there a way to accomplish what I am seeking?

Tangentially, I am also seeking clarification for the above error message in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77260926/274677).

Comment: @jcalz, yes it does. I'll edit the post to only keep the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this could work is if your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function [constrains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) one of its type parameters so that `IsEqual<T, S>` is known to be `true`.  This runs the risk of making your constraints illegally circular, so we have to be careful.  One approach looks like

```
function typeFestIsEqualAssertion<
  T extends IsEqual<T, S> extends true ? unknown : never,
  S extends IsEqual<T, S> extends true ? unknown : never
>(): void {
  console.log(true);
}
```

which luckily compiles without error.

Essentially, both `T` and `S` are constrained to `IsEqual<T, S> extends true ? unknown : never`. When you call the function and specify `T` and `S`, if `IsEqual<T, S>` is `true`, then this constraint looks like `T extends unknown, S extends unknown`, which will always work because [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) is a universal supertype in TypeScript.  On the other hand, if `IsEqual<T, S>` is not `true`, then this constraint looks like `T extends never, S extends never`, which will *almost* always fail because [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is the universal subtype in TypeScript.  The only type assignable to `never` is `never` itself.  This means you'll get your expected behavior as long as at least one of `S` and `T` is not specified as `never`.  And if *both* are `never` then presumably `IsEqual<never, never>` would be `true` and you'd be happy that it's accepted:

```
typeFestIsEqualAssertion<{ a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }>(); // error
typeFestIsEqualAssertion<{ a: 1 }, { a: 1 }>(); // okay
typeFestIsEqualAssertion<{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }>(); // error

typeFestIsEqualAssertion<{ a: 1 }, never>(); // error
typeFestIsEqualAssertion<never, { a: 1 }>(); // error
typeFestIsEqualAssertion<never, never>(); // okay
```

Note that the error messages will all say that the specified type doesn't satisfy the constraint `never`, which might or might not be acceptable for your use case.  If you need something more descriptive you'll need to work around the lack of "invalid types" or "throw types" in TypeScript.  Look at [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) for a discussion of that.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAkgZwKICOArgIYA2cAvnAGZQQhwDkSqAtDSjjEwFC80iAOwDGMYBCEJkKAGJcYuQqTIBBHDhSwJQgDy84cACpwUADxgohAExzZ8xcrqMAaOAGUAfKYtXbCKCI0AH44YQBrIQgAdykALjghFAA3LRcDDx9LGzslRzJnNy8svzsYQJCwoUiY+MSUrV5PAAoASgTkiGBrDAyRSRwIMhQAOjIIAHNm8qDWgG5eSn5WOQU8lXVNbUldTBIEgEYqNz3DtwAjBIAmKhb5uAB6B9MoeiheFfludfJNrXEdqc4EdKCc4Ptgbc2nNHs8IOESIgPjIvooHBsNP8dLtwYdjhg4Jc4DdKHcYU8Xm9lii1ujfpjtnogSC3ElUlAybDKdBkahUT81AyAXo2WkCRCQZyKVoqZ9acp6VthbpRVBWQ0OdCufDEfwgA)

Comment: I am accepting the answer as the code works but this is too magical for me.