# what is the type of IsEqual in `type-fest`?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I am writing in TypeScript and use `type-fest` for some additional type checking.

The following code:

```
function type_fest_is_equal_assertion<T, S>(): void {
      let R: IsEqual<T, S> = true; // * 
      console.log(R);
}
```

… fails at the line commented with the asterisk (`*`) with:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'IsEqual<T, S>'

The error message makes no sense to me. I though that `IsEqual` is a type alias that evaluates to a boolean type: true or false. How should I read this error message to make it make sense?

Incidentally, motivation for writing the above function is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77260345/274677).

Comment: It's presumably a generic conditional type that evaluates to `true` or `false` depending on what `T` and `S` are.  But you are unilaterally assigning `true` to it (widened to `boolean` for the error msg). Inside the body of your function the compiler cannot know if `true` is assignable, so it complains. You know `IsEqual<T, S>` is assignable to `boolean` but not the reverse. It's basically the same as the fact that you can't assign `number` to `0` but you can do the reverse.  Does that fully address the q or am I missing somehting?

Comment: @jcalz I don't get it. Surely if variable is of type `true | false` (i.e. `boolean`) I can assign `true` to it. Also it seems to me that the example you cite is the opposite case. Indeed, what I am trying to do is akin to assigning `0` to `number`, not the reverse.

Comment: If you call `typeFestIsEqualAssertion<string, number>();`, what type should `R` be?  Is it `boolean`?  No, it's `false`.  So you cannot assign `true` to it, right?  Now it's *possible* to call the function such that `R` would be `true`, but there's no *guarantee* that will happen.  Inside the body of the function the compiler truly has no idea whether `R` will be `true` or `false` or `boolean`, so it rejects the assignment of `true`.    Even if you could guarantee it by construction, the compiler cannot reason abstractly about generic conditional types: it will just reject assignments.  (more)

Comment: (continued) On the one hand you have `R` which is some *unknown subtype* of `boolean`, and on the other hand you have `true`.  You cannot them to each other safely. Both `R` and `true` are subtypes of `boolean`, so you can assign either one to `boolean`, but you cannot assign them to each other.  Does this make sense now?  Do I need to demonstrate further?  I'm happy to explain in an answer but I want to be sure we're more or less on the same page before I expend the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsEqual<T, S>` is implemented via [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), so inside the body of your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function, it is a *generic conditional type*.  Rather than rely on a third-party library I'm going to just make my own version for demonstration purposes:

```
type Eq<T, S> =
  [T] extends [S] ? [S] extends [T] ? true : false : false

function f<T, S>(): void {
  let R: Eq<T, S> = true; // error
  console.log(R);
}
```

(No, it's not exactly the same, but it demonstrates the same issue.  Feel free to replace.)  So `Eq<T, S>` will either be `true` or `false`, depending on `T` and `S`.  Inside the body of `f()`, the compiler does not know much else.  `T` and `S` are not known, and so `Eq<T, S>` represents some unknown subtype of `boolean`.  It is *not* the same as `boolean`.  If you want a value of type `boolean` I can safely give you a value of type `Eq<T, S>`, but the reverse is decidedly unsafe.  We don't know if `Eq<T, S>` will be `true` or `false`, so we cannot assign `true` to it.

For example, what if someone makes the following call?

```
f<string, number>(); // no error
```

Now we can see that `Eq<T, S>` will be `Eq<string, number>` which is `false`.  So `R` would be of type `false` and it would be a big mistake to allow assigning `true` to it.  Of course it is possible to call `f<string, string>()` and then `R` would be `true`, but that's not guaranteed inside the body of `f()`.

---

Even if you [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the `S` and `T` generics in the call signature of `f()` so that *you* are sure `Eq<T, S>` will be `true` and cannot be `false`, the compiler is unlikely to be able to perform the same reasoning.  Generic conditional types are quite often completely opaque to the compiler, so you'll still get such errors:

```
function f<
  T extends (Eq<T, S> extends true ? unknown : never),
  S extends (Eq<T, S> extends true ? unknown : never)
>(): void {
  let R: Eq<T, S> = true; // still error
  console.log(R);
}

f<string, number>(); // error now
```

---

So that's what's going on.  An even simpler demonstration is:

```
function f<R extends boolean>() {
  let R: R = true; // error
}
```

The compiler doesn't know that `true` is assignable to `R`.  All it knows is that `R` is assignable to `boolean`, which is the opposite direction from what you need.  It's almost impossible to safely assign a specific type to a generic one.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgHgCoBooGUB8UC8AoKKAbSQF0oIAPYCAOwBMBnY9cgfhfKpoeZPajAATgFdoALigAzAIYAbRhOnzFePFJG0AxsACWAe1rTkaLAAoAlJIBu+3fSgBvAlDkRgUAEqT4JjNhxBUQgAbigAenCoACooFy1DRn03ADo5fQBzM08LELwAXzUpBEZhXVoMtFoRAFsAIwghTEs8os0dAyMMhBckCmo6JigzX1R-fp4h4TEoDk0Aa1p9AHcjSVoIa0aLFBd0CcHmEcQxrAPeIJm52kWVtagNraELPGarKFt7Jxc3D29YE6mAKXUIRKKlXRyOQUIRCfRCeKJZIQNKZbK5ApqbqlITlSoPWoNJotMEwuEI9TtPSGKAACwQnnOQzq+mRMlob2+hF+XkkjMC01CBSAA)